# Правка текста с помощью регулярок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi, лямбда-выражение

Строку вида "санкт-петербург" нужно привести к виду "Санкт-Петербугрг". В Delphi метод Replace не допускает передачи лямбды, т.е. нельзя просто взять и записать нечто вроде:

```pascal
var
  s : AnsiString;
begin
  s := 'санкт-петербург';
  s := TRegEx.Replece(s, '\b(\p{L})', function(c: string): string
  begin
    // заменяем первую букву слова на заглавную
  end;)
```

Как наиболее эффективно заменить буквы на заглавные?

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант использования [`TMatchEvaluator`](https://webdelphi.ru/2010/09/delphi-xe-rabota-s-regulyarnymi-vyrazheniyami/) в качестве аргумента `class function Replace(const Input, Pattern: string; Evaluator: TMatchEvaluator): string; overload; static;`.

Comment: Отдельно определить TMatchEvaluator или что? Не уловил сути.

Comment: По ссылке подробное объяснение с примером. Проверить сам, к сожалению, не могу - нет Delphi на машине

Comment: По ссылке нет особых подробностей, но ладно.

Comment: Не уверен по поводу Delphi-реализации регэксов, но некоторые реализации - в частности PCRE - поддерживают специальные модификаторы: [Replacement Text Case Conversion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html). Т.е. замену регистра можно прописать в паттерне замены.

Comment: Похоже delphi не поддерживает такую фичу.

Comment: какие вам там еще подробности нужны-то? на входе получает совпадение и возвращает на что его заменить. В вашем случае на uppercase буквы

Comment: @Human847, Модификаторы регистра поддерживаются в Delphi (во всяком случае, в 12 Athens). Обновил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать регулярные выражения - безальтернативный вариант, то вот пример по схеме, предложенной [@Алексей Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/519463/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A0)

```Delphi
function TForm1.MatchEvaluator(const Match: TMatch): string;
begin
  Result := Match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() + // the 1st letter of the 1st part
            Match.Groups[2].Value           + // the rest of the 1st part
            Match.Groups[3].Value           + // delimiter
            Match.Groups[4].Value.ToUpper() + // the 1st letter of the 2nd part
            Match.Groups[5].Value           + // the rest of the 2nd part
end;

function TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  const input = 'сАнкТ-пеТерБург';
  
  var result := TRegEx.Replace(input.ToLower(), '(\p{L})(\p{L}*)(\-)(\p{L})(\p{L}*)', MatchEaluator);
  ShowMessage(result);
end;
```

Но я не уверен, что для данной задачи стоит использовать регулярные выражения. А ещё бывают имена и посложнее, например, Ростов-на-Дону.

P.S. Я использовал [Inline Variable Declaration](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Inline_Variable_Declaration). В старых версиях Delphi (ниже 10.3) недоступно.

---

Update. Модификаторы регистра поддерживаются в регулярках Delphi (во всяком случае, в 12 Athens).

```Delphi
function TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  const input = 'сАнкТ-пеТерБург';
  
  var result := TRegEx.Replace(input, '(\p{L})(\p{L}*)', '\U1\L2');
  ShowMessage(result);
end;
```